# Gentle explanation of 'structure-preserving map' in context of homomorphism/isomorphism?

Tags: group-homomorphism

I'm floundering with these two terms, and struggled to follow the responses given to similar questions elsewhere.

Background: I just about understand classes and groups, binary operations, and injection/bijection/surjection. However I struggle with the definitions of homomorphism and isomorphism as a 'structure-preserving mapping between two structures of the same type.' I haven't yet gotten into topology, which I note because some other answers were given in these terms.

Perhaps an example will illustrate my difficulty:

Say we have a function F(x) which takes the natural log of x, and in our example converts group A into group B.

Set A consists of 2, 3, and 6, while set B includes ln2, ln3, and ln6.

We note that 2*3 produces 6 in the first set, while in the second set we can do the same thing using addition instead. So let's say multiplication is the binary operation in the first group, and addition the binary operation in the second group.

My first question here: what is 'structure'? Is it the fact that we can link the same combinations of elements within the respective groups using its binary operation, even if the actual operation is different in each one? Which differences between the two groups would prevent the function being 'structure-preserving' and which others would be merely... superficial?

Second, what exactly are isomorphism/homomorphism a property of? Are they used to describe one or both groups, or the function, or the binary operation, or the elements?  I have seen elsewhere the example of 'log(xy) = logx + logy' as satisfying homomorphism as long as the first set is limited to positive reals. This would seem to make homo/isomorphism a property of both the original group and the transformation. Is that the best way to think about it?

(I'm going to conclude optimistically that 'mapping' probably refers to the function.)

Third, how does this relate back to injective/bijective/surjective? I'm very used to the idea that all functions can be done the opposite way and am struggling with the idea that a transformation might not be reversible, which may be the barrier to my understanding.

If you're able to address the above in a fairly self-contained way without introducing too many additional concepts I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The way I see it, operations (unary, binary, ...) satisfying nice properties give sets structure. When you have (for example) isomorphic groups, they are "basically the same" except for the elements and operations being renamed.

Comment: Being a homomorphism is IMO a property of a function, because a function has an associated domain and codomain. Restricting a function, for example, creates a different function.

Comment: I am not being quite precise. Category theory captures the spirit of these things nicely, but you should start with building a solid intuition with many simple examples, as MarianoSuárez-Álvarez wrote.

Comment: Thank you both - I'll revisit this in more detail after working through more examples in vector spaces in particular. The part about a function having an associated domain and codomain has aided my understanding a lot by bringing these two areas together